# Is it possible to open native android clock app from web application?

Tags: android, android-intent, web-applications, clock, url-scheme

I am looking for a way to open the native android alarm clock app when a user clicks on the link or button on a web browser of the android. So basically need to open the native android app from web application. I tried using `intent://#Intent;package=com.android.deskclock;end'` and it is not working. I am wondering if I am using the wrong package name or it is not even possible in android.

Thank you much for help!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents), this is not possible.  In particular, this footnote is the limiting factor:

> Only activities that have the category filter, android.intent.category.BROWSABLE are able to be invoked using this method as it indicates that the application is safe to open from the Browser.

If you look at the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/refs/heads/master/AndroidManifest.xml) for the DeskClock app, none of the activities contain the `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` category filter, meaning none of them can be opened from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that the problem is that you are not providing a URI path in your URL. It might need to be a path declared in the app's manifest. See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

This could change it to ie `intent://path/#Intent;package=com.android.deskclock;end'`

It might be helpful if you were to look at the javascript console when you try to click on that link in Chrome, there might be details of what went wrong.

Keep in mind that the alarm clock app is not necessarily consistent. Manufacturers can remove the default alarm clock app to replace it with a different one, or just modify the source code so that it has the same package name but different source code. You could try opening multiple package names from javascript depending on what happens when the intent can't be opened.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to the question. Is there a  way to find the URI for the native  clock app? How would we know the URI for it  as I was not able to get that information in the docs. Thank you in  advance for your help!

Comment: That's my point, I don't think there's a way to know it in general, you'd have to make a list

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to code party

You can get a android device IFrame from [appetize](https://appetize.io) site.

This is the easiest way for show android apps in web applications.

Update me in comments ;)